# How to generate & render url from database ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

suppose i store url in database and now i want my form action attribute or ActionLink url should point to url stored in my database. when we use ActionLink  then we specify controller & action method name and same way when we use @Html.BeginForm() then we also specify controller & action method name. so how can we customize the code for ActionLink  & BeginForm() as a result it should always point to url which is stored in database. please guide me with concept. thanks

Comment: Why not just display value in an anchor tag in the href property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me just putting the html tags with the model is too verbose I would prefrer to create a custom html helper which will encapsulate the logic behind the tag rendering you can take a look to the mvc code [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8b17c2c49f88#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/FormExtensions.cs), but it could be something like this:

```
        private static MvcForm MyFormHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {

            //you can use service locator for getting your database artifacts
            //place your custom logic

            TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
            tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            // action is implicitly generated, so htmlAttributes take precedence.
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
            // method is an explicit parameter, so it takes precedence over the htmlAttributes.
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("method", HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(method), true);

            bool traditionalJavascriptEnabled = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled
                                                && !htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled;

            if (traditionalJavascriptEnabled)
            {
                // forms must have an ID for client validation
                tagBuilder.GenerateId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormIdGenerator());
            }

            htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
            MvcForm theForm = new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);

            if (traditionalJavascriptEnabled)
            {
                htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext.FormId = tagBuilder.Attributes["id"];
            }

            return theForm;
        }
```

Comment: ViewContext.FormIdGenerator is a internal method you wont be able to just do that in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Why would you want to use the ActionLink or BeginForm helpers if you want to use an url stored in your database?

```
<a href="@Model.UrlComingFromYourDatabase">Click me</a>
```

seems just fine. Those helpers are designed to be used to compose an url by giving a controller and action names.

Comment: in case of BeginForm() how one can specify url ? suppose url is stored in variable and that variable need to use to set form action...how to do it with BeginForm() ? any guide line!

Comment: You could do it like this: `<form action="@Model.UrlComingFromYourDatabase" method="post">...</form>`.